# .map or match returning Future[List] when expected to return List

Tags: scala, asynchronous, async-await, future

I am kind of failing this weird behaviour not sure where i am wrong exactly. So the situation is that `tester2` function is returning a Future[Boolean]] now I want to wait for this to complete and when it gets completed I want it to return a List[String] based on different cases inside `reset` function, now the problem is instead of returning up a `List[String]` it is returning `Future[List[String]]` , not able to understand why match function behaving like this

I am getting this error to be exact

```
    val les = Await.ready(tester2(5),Duration.Inf).map(reset).forEach(println)
```

```
object HelloWorld {

def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val exp = tester2(5).map(reset)

    val les = Await.ready(tester2(5),Duration.Inf).map(reset).forEach(println)
    println(s"what do you say ${les}")


}
def reset (x: Option[Boolean]): List[String] =
  x match {
    case None =>  List("abc","def")
    case Some(false) =>  List("abc","def")
    case Some(true) =>  List("def","abc")
  }

def tester():Future[Option[Message]]={
    Future{
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        Option(Message("abc","def","ghi"))
    }
}
def tester2(param:Int):Future[Option[Boolean]]={
    Future{
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        if(param>10){
            Some(true)
        }else{
            Some(false)
        }
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: You've not put the error in properly. That's a line of code, possibly a copy-and-paste mistake?

Comment: You never want to `Await` a `Future` that basically destroys the whole idea of using `Future` in the first place. You want to transform it into another `Future` and keep returning that in all the chain until the main or something.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I completely understand your point , but this was just an immitation of a real life code I was trying to understand

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't think it's helpful to explain to people they can't use `Await .result`. Every single Scala program in the whole world that uses Future has at least 1 await statement... otherwise it would never produce any output. It's especially useful for grasping and studying futures in isolated pieces of code. After they can realise the potential deadlocking impact of `Await.result` and start to focus on removing all instances of it. However teaching `Await.result` is core to understanding Futures and you confuse people by omitting it. The same is true for `Option.get`

Comment: @Philluminati _"Await.result is core to understanding Futures"_ no it is not, is just a quick hack you may use in short examples or when you don't want to actually use `Futures` but you depend on a third-party library that does. - _"he same is true for Option.get"_ `Option.get` should not exists really, there is no single valid use case for it. - _"Every single Scala program in the whole world that uses Future has at least 1 await statement"_ I doubt, most **Scala** programs that use `Future` will be using a framework that accepts a `Future` as the final result and will do the dirty job.

Comment: I personally find its helps people learn and removes the magic/confusion from Futures to explain "the dirty job" is happening somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If tester2 returns a Future of an Option of a Boolean

```
def tester2(param:Int):Future[Option[Boolean] = ???
```

and you want to change the value to a string you need to say "when this future completes and there is a real Option[Boolean].. then do this thing. This is what "map" does on a future. It says "once the future completes, run this code". So you can do this:

```
def reset (in :Future[Option[Boolean]]) = in.map { optionOfBoolean :Option[Boolean] =>

    optionOfBoolean match {
        case None => ...
        case Some(true) ...
    }
}
```

Scala also allows you to short cut having the `map` and `match` together and just write:

```
def reset (in :Future[Option[Boolean]]) = in map {
    case None => List("abc", "bcd")
    case Some(true) => List("d3", "d4")
    case Some(false) => List("sds", "dssds")
}
```

Since I can't see your error I can't help you further but something like this should work.

```
val booleanResult :Future[Option[Boolean]] = tester2(...)
val futureListStr :Future[List[String]] = reset(booleanResult)
val answer :List[String] = Await.result(futureListStr, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering first of all @philuminati I want to understand , in my `reset` as you can see I am expecting to return a `List[String]`  with different values on different boolean value , my question is even when return type is `List[String]` , when I map the `reset` function on a `Future[Option[Boolean]]` it is expected to be returning a `List[String]` but instead of that it returns `Future[List[String]]` . i was confused at this part only that why it is wrapping my list inside a future

Comment: And one more thing @philuminati that , in your code I can see that you are using `await` with `futureListStr` which I just want to confirm that will it indirectly wait for the `tester2` also get completed because , because value of `futureListStr` is kind of indirectly would be depending on it

Comment: `tester2` creates a Future. "In the Future you will get this option of a boolean". `reset` calls `map` on the future. It says "when the future completes call this function". If you know what a function callback, then this should make sense. The function that's run is the block of code `{}` inside the map. It doesn't refer to the Future because the code waits until the future to run. It's safe in this way. Calling `map` on a future says apply this function to the result when we have it.. So you can turn a `Future[A]` into a `Future[B]` using function `A -> B` (what we have inside map)

Comment: But the only way to turn a `Future[X]` back into an `X` is to `Await.result` on it. That's what  I do at the end of the program. Wait for everything to happen. I could rearrange the code so `reset` takes an `Option[Boolean]` returns `List[String]` (basically the stuff in the map part of the function) and then I could either do:

`val innner = Await.result(tester2, Duration.Inf); val answer = reset(inner)`

or I could keep the map

`val answer = Await.result(tester2(..).map(reset), Duration.Inf)`

The last is particularly clean

Answer (score 1):

Use [Await.result](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Await$.html#result%5BT%5D(awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable%5BT%5D,atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T) to extract the result value.

> ```scala
> final def result[T](awaitable: Awaitable[T], atMost: Duration): T
> ```
>
> Await and return the result (of type T) of an Awaitable.
>
> **awaitable** the Awaitable to be awaited
>
> **atMost** maximum wait time, which may be negative (no waiting is done), >Duration.Inf for unbounded waiting, or a finite positive duration
>
> **returns** the result value if awaitable is completed within the specific maximum wait time